# Rails Devise NON HTML email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I've following setting in my Application.rb file

```
Devise::Mailer.layout "Mailer Layout Name"
```

I'm sending both HTML and NON-HTML(text) emails. I want to ignore the "**Devise::Mailer.layout**" for Non-HTML(text) email. Is there anyway to get this done in Devise and Rails.

I'm using Rails 4.2.4 & devise (3.5.1)

Answer (score 0):

This is standard *ActionMailer* functionality, not related to *Devise*.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout :layout

  private

  def layout
    'my-layout' if content_type == 'text/html'
  end
end
```